# How to display image using xamarin in android project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I trying to display a images in android project using xamarin.

1. I put folder `Images` in my android project in directory `Resources/drawable/Images`
2. I set on every image property `AndroidResource` from `BuildAction` (I'm not sure if that should be the case)
3. In the c# code I try to call the image with this code but not worked for me:

   ```
    if (descriptionForecast1 == "clear sky")
                {
                    ImageDescriptionForecast1.Source = "Images/ClearSky.jpg";
                    ImageForecast1.Source = "Images/ClearSky.jpg";
                }
   ```

Can I get an example of how to call the Images, because I get an error like this that the path is wrong:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(3,3): Error APT2144: invalid file path '/Users/pizhev/Projects/WeatherLocationInfo 0.0.1/WeatherLocationInfo.Android/obj/Debug/res/drawable/images/lightrain1.jpg'. (APT2144) (WeatherLocationInfo.Android)
```

Comment: Check the docs [local-images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images)

Comment: Is there a way to call them as I call them at iOS project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images)

> Android - Place images in the Resources/drawable directory with Build
> Action: AndroidResource. High- and low-DPI versions of an image can
> also be supplied (in appropriately named Resources subdirectories such
> as drawable-ldpi, drawable-hdpi, and drawable-xhdpi).

do not create your own sub-folders in Resources

Comment: I will try this and will give feedback on your answer :)